# How to parametrize counterclockwise a triangle?

Tags: complex-analysis, triangles

Given three distincts complex numbers $a,b,c$, how to parametrize counterclockwise the boundary of the triangle with vertices $a,b$ and $c$ ? Thanks in advance for help :)

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The segment from $a$ to $b$ is parametrized by $(1-t)a+tb$ with $0\le t\le 1$.

Comment: I know how to parametrize segments (and a triangle) but, it's the "counterclockwise" condition I stuck on.

Comment: how the point are allocated?

Comment: The vertices are arbitrary (different) points

Comment: they shouldn't be on a line, but if they are not on a line, you should only  parametrize each segment in counterclockwise direction about triangle

Comment: Assume that the three points are differents and not on a line, if I choose the smallest point in the sens of lexicographical order on $\mathbb C$, how to select the next point in order to parametrize counterclockwise the boundary ?

Comment: A try that it may help: take $a=A+iP$, $b=B+iQ$ and $c=C+iR$, and seek among $A,B,C$ the greatest with the imaginary part the lowest, and name it the 1st, then walk to the next who have the minimum $P,Q,R$ which is not the imaginary part of the 1st, call it the 2nd...

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1022109)

Comment: If I compute a determinant which represents the area of the triangle with a sign $+$ or $-$, does positiveness mean the counterclockwise orientation ?

Comment: @Phoenix: on which matrix?

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco do you see the foreword *Hint* at the beginning?

Comment: With real and imaginary parts over the two first rows, and 1 on the last row : $\det\begin{pmatrix}A&B&C\\P&Q&R\\1&1&1\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: the problem with this matrix is that in interchanging 2 columns the determinant jumps from positive to negative or negative to positive

Comment: If $a=A+iP$, $b=B+iQ$ and $c=C+iR$ and boundary goes from $a$ to $b$, then from $b$ to $c$ and from $c$ to $a$, positiveness means that we crossed the lines without going back I think...